# Display a grouped product's minimal non sale price in Magento listing page

Tags: magento

I am trying to display both the non sale price as well as the sale price on the Magento listing page. Similar to the way it works to simple products when it is on sale.

For example:

From: <strike>£40.00</strike> £28.00

So realistically we would need to find out the minimal non sale price. The minimal sale price is already being displayed on default.

I would prefer having an efficient solution of course - which does not require too much processing!

I would be extremely grateful for any help or suggestions!

Comment: could you please clear me you want to show minimum non sale price from all prices that we can set via admin for the product right ? however there is for way in which we can set this simple price,special price, tier price group price and you want to show minimal non sale price among this M i right ?

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your reply! In regards to clarification. Say we have a grouped master product being displayed on the listing page. This product has associated products which are currently on sale. The listing page currently shows the price in this format: From: £23.00 (which is the lowest sale price) I want to actually calculate the similar lowest price (the cheapest associated product's non sale price) So in theory get the lowest non sale price from the associated products and display it. Hope this makes sense.